# xcodebuild - set certificate through commandline

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, xcodebuild

I have an Xcode project for an iOS application.

I plan building it through commandline using xcodebuild.

I will be adding minor customizations from build to build, producing slightly different versions of the application (for branding purpose).

What I need is a way to automatically set a specific certificate for each build. Is it possible to somehow set a certificate for the build through command line?

To clarify - every time I build the project, I want to use a new certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the build, set environment variable `CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY="name of certificate"`

Comment: Xcode's build setting (as at version 13.2.1 anyway) seems to be `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` (i.e 'sign', not 'signing')